# How can I fix uncaught reference and null error in the the JS Rock, Papers, Scissors game?

Tags: javascript, function, debugging

I am getting an error in line 15 of  the game.js file. My code saying that there is an uncaught reference error and is undefined. Can anyone help me to figure out how to fix this error?  And can anyone tell me why it is causing this error?

I can't seem to figure out why my getChoices function is returning a null value. Can anyone tell me how to fix this and why it is causing an error?

And can you check the rest of my code for any more error(s) and how I can fix them?

```js
var $ = function (id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

window.onload = function () {
  $("show").onclick = getChoices;
}

function getChoices() {
  var player_choice = $("player_choice").onclick.value;
  var computer_choice = math.Random();
  getChoices();
}   

if(computer_choice <= 0.33 )
{
  computer_choice = "Rock";
}

else if(computer_choice <= 0.66)
{
  computer_choice= "Paper";
}

else 
{
  computer_choice = "Scissors";
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{
  if(choice1 === choice2)
  {
    return "The result is a tie!";
  }

  else if(choice1 === "Rock"){
    if(choice2 === "Scissors")  
    {
      return "Rock wins";
    }
    else
    {
      return "Paper wins";
    }
  }

  else if(choice1 === "Paper")
  {
    if(choice2 === "Rock")
    {
      return "Paper wins";
    }
    else
    {
      return "Scissors wins";
    }
  }

  else if(choice1 === "Scissors")
  {
    if(choice2 === "Paper")
    {
      return "Scissors wins";
    }
    else
    {
      return "Rock wins";
    }
  }
};

compare(player_choice,computer_choice);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Shipping Order Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script src="assets/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="player_choice">Select either rock, paper or scissors:
</label>
      <select name="player_choice" id="player_choice" class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="rock">rock</option>
        <option value="paper">paper</option>
        <option value="scissors">scissors</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Show" name="show"     
id="show" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: declare computer_choice in global as you are defining it inside a function and using outside moreover its Math.random() and not math.Random()

Comment: your getChoices seems to call itself and will just keep going in a loop if you fix the math.Random error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code of js file.

1. In the HTML, you have used lower cases for the Ids of the choice which is not the case in your js.
2. Also, the getChoices() is recursively called, this  makes no sense as the code seems to be doing nothing.
3. I don't think the computer's choice is ever being recorded.

I think you will have to rectify all that for it to work.

*Edit: Also, As Vinod said, you should declare the choices variables as global.*

Comment: I declared the computer_choice and player_choice as a global variable.

Comment: Also, how can I record the computer's choice. And how can I fix the getChoices function to get the input value from the user.